# Nonetype check in django conditional expressions

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

*emphasized text*Let's say we have two models, as below:

```py
class DefaultDescription(models.Model):
    first_attr = models.IntegerField()
    second_attr = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class SomeEntity(models.Model):
    first_attr = models.IntegerField()
    second_attr = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    # and some other unimportant attributes...

    @property
    def description(self):
        try:
            return DefaultDescription.objects.get(first_attr=self.first_attr, second_attr=self.second_attr).description
        except DefaultDescription.DoesNotExist:
            return ''
```

What I want to do is to write a single query for `SomeEntity` to fetch all of the descriptions. As you can see, the `description` property will run a queryset, which means a queryset for each entity. So I've tried some queryset like this:

```py
class DescriptionAnnotationQS(models.QuerySet):
    def annotate_descriptions(self):
        self.annotate(
            desc=models.Case(
                models.When(
                    DefaultDescription.objects.filter(
                        first_attr=models.F('first_attr'),
                        second_attr=models.F('second_attr')).exists(),
                    then=models.Value(DefaultDescription.objects.get(
                        first_attr=models.F('first_attr'),
                        second_attr=models.F('second_attr')).description)),
                default=models.Value('')
            )
        )
```

I used `Case` and `When` to check if there wasn't any default description for the entity. But still I get `DoesNotExist` exception! I thought `then` section will not be executed unless the condition returns `True`, but apparently it'll run either way.

Is there any way to annotate `SomeEntity` with description with none type check?

P.S: I faced this problem from a legacy code which I'm not allowed to establish relations between its models.